# WPF Image to byte[]

Tags: c#, wpf, image, arrays

I'm trying to convert from `System.Windows.Controls.Image` to `byte[]` and I didnt know which method from Image class could help in this scenary, by the way I really dont know what should I do, cause in my LINQ model the field appears as `Binary` type, I have to change this if I want to save it like a `byte[]` type?

I found code posted here, but without using WPF:

```
Bitmap newBMP = new Bitmap(originalBMP, newWidth, newHeight);
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
newBMP.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
PHJProjectPhoto myPhoto = new PHJProjectPhoto {
    ProjectPhoto = stream.ToArray(), // <<--- This will convert your stream to a byte[] 
    OrderDate = DateTime.Now, 
    ProjectPhotoCaption = ProjectPhotoCaptionTextBox.Text,
    ProjectId = selectedProjectId
};
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Real Solution... if want to save jpg images from an System.Windows.Control.Image when your database mapped field on your ORM is Byte[] / byte[] / Bynary

```
public byte[] getJPGFromImageControl(BitmapImage imageC)
{
       MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();              
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(imageC));
        encoder.Save(memStream);
        return memStream.ToArray();
}
```

call as :

```
getJPGFromImageControl(firmaUno.Source as BitmapImage)
```

Hopes helps :)

Comment: yeah... but rather slow, 470+ miliseconds...:(

Answer (score 12):

I don't know how your Image is declared, but suppose we have this XAML declaration:

```
<Image x:Name="img">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="test.png" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Then you can convert the contents of test.png to a byte-array like this:

```
var bmp = img.Source as BitmapImage;

int height = bmp.PixelHeight;
int width  = bmp.PixelWidth;
int stride = width * ((bmp.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);

byte[] bits = new byte[height * stride];
bmp.CopyPixels(bits, stride, 0);
```

Comment: my xaml is : 
            <Image Margin="6" Name="firmaUno" Stretch="Fill">
            </Image>  
Im setting source in codebehind, so which is better?

Comment: surprise is saving :

0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...

:/

Comment: I prefer this method cause we can save any fileType to byteArray :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public byte[] BufferFromImage(BitmapImage imageSource)
{        
    Stream stream = imageSource.StreamSource;
    byte[] buffer = null;

    if (stream != null && stream.Length > 0)
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            buffer = br.ReadBytes((Int32)stream.Length);
        }
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

would be another way, but difference is this have less bytes[x] than first solution

Comment: I think it depends on how you initialize the image. If you set a BitmapImage StreamSource seems to be null.

Comment: I am setting the Image.Source as BitmapImage and getting a null BitmapImage back, I also tried to cast to BitmapImage, what is the workaround for this? It seems like an invalid cast, yet I see this solution everywhere including http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/dee0e287-b345-4e01-888a-ecfb9c3f40b0/.

Answer (score 2):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var of = new OpenFileDialog();
        of.Filter = "Image files (*.png;*.jpeg)|*.png;*.jpeg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        var res = of.ShowDialog();
        if (res.HasValue)
        {
            imgPreview.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(of.FileName));

            var t = Utils.ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(imgPreview.Source as BitmapSource);
            var d = Utils.ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(new BitmapImage(new Uri(of.FileName)));
            var s = Utils.ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(imgPreview.Source);
            var enc = Utils.ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(new PngBitmapEncoder(), imgPreview.Source);
            //imgPreview2.Source = Utils.ConvertByteArrayToBitmapImage(enc);
            imgPreview2.Source = Utils.ConvertByteArrayToBitmapImage2(enc);
            //var i = 0;


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select a currect file...");

        }
    }

}
```

/*util.cs*/

```
public class Utils
{
    public static byte[] ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(BitmapEncoder encoder, ImageSource imageSource)
    {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        var bitmapSource = imageSource as BitmapSource;

        if (bitmapSource != null)
        {
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                encoder.Save(stream);
                bytes = stream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return bytes;
    }

    public static byte[] ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(BitmapSource image)
    {
        byte[] data;
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return data;
    }
    public static byte[] ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(ImageSource imageSource)
    {
        var image = imageSource as BitmapSource;
        byte[] data;
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return data;
    }
    public static byte[] ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(Uri uri)
    {
        var image = new BitmapImage(uri);
        byte[] data;
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return data;
    }
    public static byte[] ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(string filepath)
    {
        var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filepath));
        byte[] data;
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static BitmapImage ConvertByteArrayToBitmapImage(Byte[] bytes)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.StreamSource = stream;
        image.EndInit();
        return image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like encoders and decoders from the namespace: [System.Windows.Media.Imaging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static class Extensions {        

    public static byte[] ToByteArray(this BitmapSource bitmapSource) {

        var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
            encoder.Save(stream);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(this byte[] bytes) {

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes)) {
            var decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            return decoder.Frames.First();
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var bytes = bitmapSource.ToByteArray();
```

Or like this:

```
var bitmapSource = bytes.ToBitmapSource();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
MemoryStream stream = (MemoryStream)bitmapImage.StreamSource;
byte[] data = stream.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use BitmapSources's CopyPixels method

```
int stride = snapshot.PixelWidth * (snapshot.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8);
byte[] data = new byte[stride * snapshot.PixelHeight];
snapshot.CopyPixels(data, stride, 0);
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data);
```