# Saving Bitmap Images in WPF via C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, bitmapimage

I display images in my WPF app using `BitmapImage`.
However, I would like an easy way to save these (as JPG) to a different location (ideally into a `Stream` or object that can be passed around).

Is it possible using `BitmapImage` or do I have to use other means? If so what other means are there for either loading an `Image` and saving as JPG or converting a `BitmapImage` into this element to then save off?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
public byte[] GetJPGFromImageControl(BitmapImage imageC)
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(imageC));
    encoder.Save(memStream);
    return memStream.GetBuffer();
}
```

(from: [WPF Image to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553611/wpf-image-to-byte))