# Converting a PNG compressed byte array to BMP byte array

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap, png

I am having this issue and none of the solutions I've read fits in so far. I'm after some wisdom..

I have a Base64 encoded string, which is derived from a PNG image. I have to supply to crystal reports a byte array of Bitmap. Easy to get the byte array from Base64 string of course... so I need some help going from PNG byte array to Bitmap byte array...

Any ideas? Using .NET 3.5 Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a `PngBitmapDecoder`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970062.aspx

Comment: I already found that. The Image class used there (System.Windows.Controls.Image) does not have a save function. So I can't seem to save it back into a byte array...

Comment: Sure you can; use `BmpBitmapEncoder` next. Its `Save` method will write it out to the storage medium of your choice (including a memory buffer). Or just build up a BMP header yourself, it's really trivial to do.

Comment: Ah... I was just going to say that. Completely didn't think of using BmpEncoder... Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. If this is working for you, an upvote or accept would be appreciated :)

Comment: Hey, all I get when I go from PngDecoder to BmpEncoder is a black box...

PngBitmapDecoder decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
                                        BitmapSource source = decoder.Frames[0];
BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
                                        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));
MemoryStream bitmapStream = new MemoryStream();
                                        encoder.Save(bitmapStream);

Can you help?

Comment: When you look at the bytes in the memory stream, does it look like image data or like a solid wall of one value (probably 0)?

Comment: my issue turned out to be a lot different to what I had initially thought. The black box was being generated due to PNG's transparency being dropped during conversion. I managed to create a Graphics object and draw the PNG into that before getting out the bytes. In any case, appreciate your help and I have marked you as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Winform Image class provide Save method.

For WPF, refer to:
[WPF Image to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553611/wpf-image-to-byte)