# Bitmap to Base64String 

Tags: c#, wpf, string, image, bitmap

i am trying to convert a bitmap to a base64 string.i can convert to from string to bitmap...but it seems like there is a problem when converting from bitmap to string.I was hoping you guys could give me a hand

```
    public static string BitmapToString(BitmapImage image)
    {

        Stream stream = image.StreamSource ;
        Byte[] buffer = null;
        if (stream != null && stream.Length > 0)
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                buffer = br.ReadBytes((Int32)stream.Length);
            }
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
    }
```

it gets a ArgumentNullException was unhandled 
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: inArray
when returning  Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)

Help?

Comment: Are you sure you enter the `if`? I think the problem is that the image has been loaded from an url and so there isn't any stream.

Comment: doesnt enter the if..the thing is it says that the image.StreamSource is null..but it does get the right image

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553611/wpf-image-to-byte (the accepted solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this alternative:

```
 public string BitmapToBase64(BitmapImage bi)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bi));
            encoder.Save(ms);
            byte[] bitmapdata = ms.ToArray();

            return Convert.ToBase64String(bitmapdata);
        }
```

[In your solution, it is not necessary that StreamSource will always have value if it is loaded using a Uri.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Remarks)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is necessary to save `BitmapImage` data into memory using some bitmap encoder (`PngBitmapEncoder` for example).

```
public static byte[] EncodeImage(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
        encoder.Save(memoryStream);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then just encode the binary data with Base64-encoding.

```
const string filePath = @"...";
const string outFilePath = @"...";
const string outBase64FilePath = @"...";

// Constuct test BitmapImage instance.
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.BeginInit();
bitmapImage.StreamSource = File.OpenRead(filePath);
bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bitmapImage.EndInit();

// Convert BitmapImage to byte array.
byte[] imageData = EncodeImage(bitmapImage);
File.WriteAllBytes(outFilePath, imageData);

// Encode with Base64.
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageData);

// Write to file (for example).
File.WriteAllText(outBase64FilePath, base64String);
```