# how can i save an image converting to blob in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I need to convert a blob image and insert to **MYSQL** database..and need to retrieve that data and load in the picture box

Comment: here's a converter class [C# Image to Byte Array and Byte Array to Image Converter Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv)

Comment: Jus Googled it, u had got 10000 results.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at

[IMage - To  - Byte - Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553611/wpf-image-to-byte)

And

[Byte - Arrray - To - Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564174/convert-byte-array-to-image-in-wpf)

This two links can solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
v_file_data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"]);
```