# Save image to phone storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I have image control and I want to save this image to phone storage.
So, I have Image control and below button. When user click the button, image should be saved to phone storage.
How can I do this ?

I found code:

```
 // Create a file name for the JPEG file in isolated storage.
        String tempJPEG = "TempJPEG";

        // Create a virtual store and file stream. Check for duplicate tempJPEG files.
        var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (myStore.FileExists(tempJPEG))
        {
            myStore.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
        }

        IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(tempJPEG);


        // Create a stream out of the sample JPEG file.
        // For [Application Name] in the URI, use the project name that you entered 
        // in the previous steps. Also, TestImage.jpg is an example;
        // you must enter your JPEG file name if it is different.
        StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
        Uri uri = new Uri("[Application Name];component/TestImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

        // Create a new WriteableBitmap object and set it to the JPEG stream.
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
        bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

        // Encode the WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream.
        wb.SaveJpeg(myFileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
        myFileStream.Close();

        // Create a new stream from isolated storage, and save the JPEG file to the media library on Windows Phone.
        myFileStream = myStore.OpenFile(tempJPEG, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        // Save the image to the camera roll or saved pictures album.
        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();


        Picture pic = library.SavePicture("SavedPicture.jpg", myFileStream);
        MessageBox.Show("Image saved to saved pictures album");


        myFileStream.Close();
```

But how I can put my image from image control here ?

Comment: A quick use of the search function will give you multiple answers to your question.

Comment: If that's the case, why not post a link? You could argue that about most questions on SO

Comment: BOOOOOOOOM!!!! @MaximGershkovich

Answer (score 3):

Simple example saving to Isolated Storage from image control.

```
Stream ImageStream = (MyImageControl.Source as BitmapImage).GetStream();

IsolatedStorageFile IsoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream storageStream = IsoStore.CreateFile("TestImage.bmp"))                             
   ImageStream.CopyTo(storageStream);


public static Stream GetStream(this BitmapImage image)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();              
    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
    encoder.Save(stream);
    return stream;
}
```

`GetStream` extension is taken from this answer [WPF Image to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553611/wpf-image-to-byte). I haven't tested this code but it should get you on the right track.

Comment: The only addition I would have to the above answer is if you are afraid of working with isolated storage. Try out the free DLL I wrote. Its called EZ_Iso.DLL and is available for free use and download at http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=47  With a single method call you can save/retrieve any object to the isolated storage. Completely removing the need for all of the above complicatedness