# How to save rotated image WritebaleBitmap in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I tried following code to rotate image on button click event,

```
if (btn.Text.Equals("Rotate"))
{
    if (angle >= 360)
        angle = 0;

    angle += 90;
    RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();
    rt.Angle = angle;
    img.RenderTransform = rt;       
}
```

using above code image get rotated 90 degree in addition to previous rotation on button click.

I want to save that rotated image using `WritableBitmap`. 
How can I save it?

Comment: Something like this? [Save image to phone storage](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19793769/2596334)

Comment: @Okuma.Scott I tried code from the link you suggested but i get error for (img.Source as BitmapImage).GetStream(); method GetStream() for BitmapImage not found.

Answer (score 1):

I tried following steps and it worked for saving rotated image with WritableBitmap,

Step 1) Placed Image control inside StackPanel control as mentioned below,

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" Height="400" Width="400"  Margin="0, 50, 0, 50" >
    <Image x:Name="img" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Grid.Row="1" Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="400" Width="400" >
         <Image.RenderTransform>
             <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform" />
         </Image.RenderTransform> 
    </Image>
</StackPanel>
```

Step 2) Used following code to save WitableBitmap using StackPanel "ContentPanel" as I added Image control on ContentPanel,

```
IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

if (isolatedStorage.FileExists(filePath))
   isolatedStorage.DeleteFile(filePath);

var fileStream = isolatedStorage.CreateFile(filePath);

WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(ContentPanel, null);

wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

fileStream.Close();
```