# Convert System.Windows.Media.ImageSource to ByteArray

Tags: c#, wpf

is there a way to convert a ImageSource object to byte array?
I have an ImageSource object bound to a WPF window, i can convert a byte array from the data base and convert it to ImageSource but i can't do it the reverse way.

Thx in advance.

Edit: I tried to convert ImageSource as BitmapImage but got a null object.

Comment: Check the property FileBytes

Comment: HI, there is no such a property.

Comment: What is the code you're trying to use now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553611/wpf-image-to-byte

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even if your ImageSource is not a BitmapImage you may still successfully cast it to `BitmapSource`, which is the base class of all WPF bitmap classes like BitmapImage, BitmapFrame, WriteableBitmap, RenderTargetBitmap etc. (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx#inheritanceContinued)).

So in case your ImageSource is actually a BitmapSource (and not a DrawingImage or a D3DImage), the following method converts it to a byte array by using the specified BitmapEncoder (e.g. a PngBitmapEncoder):

```
public byte[] ImageSourceToBytes(BitmapEncoder encoder, ImageSource imageSource)
{
    byte[] bytes = null;
    var bitmapSource = imageSource as BitmapSource;

    if (bitmapSource != null)
    {
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(stream);
            bytes = stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return bytes;
}
```