# How to save an image into a database?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I am using WPF to insert an image to my MySQL database. I can upload the file to image control but I don't know how to save it.

Here is what I've done so far. The `emp_image` is the image control that displays the photo.

```
private void btn_save_image_click(object sender,...)   
{   
    Mysqlconnection cn= new mysqlconnection(connectionstring);    
    byte[] imagedata;    
    imagedata=File.ReadAllBytes(emp_img);  //..here is error,it says has invalid arguments..//
    mysqlcommand= new mysqlcommand("insert into dep_table(photo)values(?data)",cn);    
    cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("?data", imagedata);    
    cn.open();    
    cmd.executeNonQuery();    
    cn.close();
}
```

Comment: what type is "emp_img"

Comment: It would be a better idea to store the **path** to the image as opposed to the image itself.

Comment: @Nikita emp_img is an image control where image is shown and i want to save that image to database table

Comment: Is `emp_img` the correct file path?

Comment: @MikeEason you mean giving the path from openfile dialoge ?

Comment: what is the Imagesource look like for the control. Is it a path/URI??? add an example

Comment: `emp_img` is a control and not an image file --> you should put the file path into that function. A suggestion is, you should not save image in database. You should store the image on disk. And just save the file path to that image to database.

Comment: question is not related to database at all, you have a problem reading a file from disk, probably because you are specifying an invalid path

Comment: @MikeEason@Nikita the image source is :    emp_img.source= new bitmapImage(new Uri(dlg.FileName));

Comment: @SmartGoat thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to convert the image source to byte[] :

```
public static byte[] ImageToArray(BitmapSource image)
{
    var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Save(stream);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then, call the function:

```
imagedata = ImageToArray((BitmapSource)emp_img.Source);
```

Comment: wbmp.SaveJpeg is not availbale! is there any namespace missing?

Comment: System.Windows.Media.Imaging

Comment: I already have it. but it says that it doesn't contain a definition for 'SaveJpeg'

Comment: SaveJpeg is Windows Phone.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/554455/1136211), but replace `memStream.GetBuffer()` by `memStream.ToArray()`.

Comment: Yes, found it.checking for alternative using Encoders

Comment: Also use `BitmapSource` instead of `BitmapImage` as argument type (so that it also supports `BitmapFrame`). Cast the `Image.Source` property to `BitmapSource`.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you are not passing the file path.

Please check [File::ReadAllBytes Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Should be something like

```
var imagedata=File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
```

Comment: this is better a comment than a reply